# python numerically solving an equation with no sign change between the upper and lower bound

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.x

I am trying to solve an equation but I am unable to use `brentq` since there is no sign change.  How could I find the value of `r`?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> def f(r):
    return 0.1 + 1 / (2 * r ** 2) - 2 / (3 * np.sqrt(r ** 3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is sign change, but you can solve it by `fsolve`:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np

def f(r):
    return 0.1 + 1 / (2 * r ** 2) - 2 / (3 * np.sqrt(r ** 3))

r = fsolve(f, 1)
f(r)
```

result:

```
r = 2.22213541
```

**Edit**

There are two solution:

```
import numpy as np

def f(r):
    return 0.1 + 1 / (2 * r ** 2) - 2 / (3 * np.sqrt(r ** 3))

r = np.linspace(0.6, 3, 1000)
plot(r, f(r))
```

output:

[image]

Comment: the solution is supposed to 0.667.  All that was needed was to set 1 to .1